# Need help for trigger implementation

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I have implemented one logic in which,on update of case-there is one picklist(**`X2nd_Level_Support_Needed__c`**-**`Yes/No`**). On Yes there is one lookup on Case object **`Equipment__c`**- My trigger is checking the one field(**`Fleet_Owner_PLC__c`**) on **`Equipment__c`** and its checking same value in custom setting.

If Its found then on custom setting there is one field **`QueueName`** and it will check queue and send mail to that queuemembers. Currently it is working for one case only.if i am updating multiple cases then its sending multiple mails.Please help me to correct logic as i am new to code.

```
trigger UpdateOnCase on Case(after update) {
    set < Id > equipmentIds = new set < Id > ();
    Map < Id, String > mapQNameWithIds = new Map < Id, String > ();
    Map < String, String > emailMap = new Map < String, String > ();
    List < String > sendTo = new List < String > ();
    List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > mails = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > ();
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    for (QueueSobject so: [select QueueId, Queue.Name, SobjectType from QueueSObject where SobjectType = 'case']) {
        mapQNameWithIds.put(so.queueId, so.queue.name);
    }
    for (
        case cases:
            trigger.new) {
        case Oldcase = Trigger.oldMap.get(cases.Id);
        if ((Oldcase.X2nd_Level_Support_Needed__c != cases.X2nd_Level_Support_Needed__c) && cases.X2nd_Level_Support_Needed__c == 'Yes') {
            if (cases.Equipment__c != null) {
                equipmentIds.add(cases.Equipment__c);
            }
        }
    }
    Map < Id, Equipment__c > EquipmentWithIdmap = new Map < Id, Equipment__c > ([SELECT Fleet_Owner_PLC__c from Equipment__c where id in: equipmentIds]);
    Equipment__c equip;
    list < String > queuename = new list < String > ();
    map < id, string > GroupIds = new map < id, string > ();
    list <
        case >caselist = new list <
        case >();
    for (
        case cse:
            trigger.new) {
        case Oldcase = Trigger.oldMap.get(cse.Id);

        if ((Oldcase.X2nd_Level_Support_Needed__c != cse.X2nd_Level_Support_Needed__c) && cse.X2nd_Level_Support_Needed__c == 'Yes') {
            if (EquipmentWithIdmap.size() > 0)
                if (cse.Equipment__c != null) {
                    caselist.add(cse);
                    equip = EquipmentWithIdmap.get(cse.Equipment__c);
                    // queuename.add(euip.Fleet_Owner_PLC__c);
                    for (Default_Case_Queue__c casedefaultSetting: Default_Case_Queue__c.getAll().values()) {
                        system.debug('**************2');
                        if (casedefaultSetting.Fleet_PLC__c.equals(equip.Fleet_Owner_PLC__c)) {
                            queuename.add(casedefaultSetting.X2nd_level_Queue__c);

                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    if (queuename.size() > 0) {
        for (User u: [SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id IN(SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE Group.Name IN: queuename)]) {
            if (u.email != null)
                sendTo.add(u.email);
        }
        List <
            case >EuipmentList = new List <
            case >([select id, Description, Subject, CaseNumber, Equipment__c, Contact.name, Equipment__r.name
                from
                case where id in :
                    caseList
            ]);
        for (
            case c:
                EuipmentList) {
            mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('' + c.id + 'Test Sender name');
            body += '<b>' + 'Contact---' + '</b>' + c.contact.Name + '<br/>';
            body += '<b>Subject---</b>' + c.subject + '<br/>';
            body += '<b>Description---</b>' + c.Description + '<br/>';
            mail.setHtmlBody(body);
            mails.add(mail);
            if (!mails.isEmpty()) {
                Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull the `Messaging.sendEmail(mails);` method out of the for loop.  This then send all the emails at once instead of each mail separately.

```
    for( case c:EuipmentList){
        mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
        mail.setSenderDisplayName(''+c.id+'Test Sender name');             
        body += '<b>'+'Contact---'+'</b>'+c.contact.Name+'<br/>';
        body += '<b>Subject---</b>'+c.subject+'<br/>';
        body += '<b>Description---</b>'+c.Description+'<br/>';      
        mail.setHtmlBody(body);
        mails.add(mail);
    }  
    if(!mails.isEmpty()){
        Messaging.sendEmail(mails); 
    }
```

**Update**

In line 8 you have this line `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();`  move it down into your for loop

```
    for( case c:EuipmentList){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
        mail.setSenderDisplayName(''+c.id+'Test Sender name');             
        body += '<b>'+'Contact---'+'</b>'+c.contact.Name+'<br/>';
        body += '<b>Subject---</b>'+c.subject+'<br/>';
        body += '<b>Description---</b>'+c.Description+'<br/>';      
        mail.setHtmlBody(body);
        mails.add(mail);
    }  
    if(!mails.isEmpty()){
        Messaging.sendEmail(mails); 
    }
```

What was happening is that you were only declaring a single email and in your for loop just resetting the properties on each iteration of the for loop. Moving that line to your for loop will generate an email for each case in the `EuipmentList`.

Comment: but in sendTo list all emails are coming.but i want to send email to queuemembers based on case ewuipment field.

Comment: @ajaybagdad I'm not entirely sure what you are asking.  Do you want to send Emails only to Users in one specific Queue?

Comment: Yes correct.I want to send email to specific queue members for particular case if condition match  like  case update-->if yes-->check equipment lookup field on case-->get fleet owner plc from equipment--->if same value in custom setting-->get custom setting field(Queue_name) value from custom setting--->search queue-->if found-->send mail to that queuemebers

Comment: currently it is working for one queue,But when i am updating multiple using dataloader it is not working as expected

Comment: @ajaybagdad If I understand you correctly you are saying that currently it finds more than 1 queue, but the email only gets sent to the Users of 1 queue, and you need the emails to get sent to Users of all Queues?  Correct?

Comment: {if(queuename.size()>0){
        for(User u:[SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id IN (SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE Group.Name IN: queuename) ]){
            if(u.email != null)
                sendTo.add(u.email);
        }                                                                                                                          here i am adding users of all queuenames in a SendTo list ......and then sending email..so it is not case specific its sending email to every users in SendTo List

Comment: @ajaybagdad I updated my answer.  I think this should solve your problem.